# PHP or Javascript Capability - Forcefully log out of facebook with 1 click if possible

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I would like to if possible have an iframe open for facebook on my site, and create a button that would forcefully log out the current account that i am on regardless of timeline style and element classes etc. is there a way to forcefully disconnect the session so that the next time the page is visited it would require a log in?  either through php or javascript.

Comment: Please share what you have tried

Comment: I have tried using javascript to pin point the elements and log out, and it works however there are different types of timelines and i was wondering if it was possible with either language to disconnect the current account's session, making it so that a login would be required on the next visit

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Facebook's provided SDK, because the way that you are doing it now seems kind of hacky and might even violate Facebook's terms of service.

Facebook Javascript SDK:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Facebook Logout function:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

You can trigger this function with your button click:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
});
```